# How to delete all live TV channels in Windows Media Center?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

I made some modifications in the configuration of the signal of the live TV channels in Windows Media Center (for Windows 7). Now I want to delete all that was stored before, to reorganize them again.

But I can't seem to find a way to delete all the channels. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

For digital TV channels, you could go to *Settings* / *TV Signal* / *Digital TV Antenna Signal Strength*, select a tuner, then uncheck each channel.

Comment: I believe this will disable the channels not delete them?

Comment: Disabling the channel effectively removes it from all other lists.  Otherwise it seems like you need to perform another channel scan (i.e. setup the TV again), maybe with the antenna disconnected and then manually add back channels.